# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change container ID of fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I try to swap the positions of the two fragments by clicking on the button.
First, I add tow FrameLayout in my xml file.

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame_small"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:rotation="90" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/big_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And then add the fragments when initView

```
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    findViewById(R.id.content_frame_small).bringToFront();
    if (mapFragment == null) {
        mapFragment = new MapFragment();
    }
    ft.addToBackStack(MapFragment.TAG);
    ft.add(R.id.content_frame_small, mapFragment, MapFragment.TAG);
    if (cameraPreviewFragment == null) {
        cameraPreviewFragment = new CameraPreviewFragment();
    }
    ft.addToBackStack(CameraPreviewFragment.TAG);
    ft.add(R.id.big_fragment, cameraPreviewFragment, CameraPreviewFragment.TAG);
    ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

But the small fragment has not been shown！I tried to swap two fragments' position, but the small ones still did not appear. And when I try to change their position by click a button it appear:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change container ID of fragment MapFragment{43138b40 #0 id=0x7f110098 MapFragment}: was 2131820696 now 2131820697
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:406)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.add(BackStackRecord.java:375)
                                                                           at com.locision.ogipssampler.activity.CameraRecordActivity.onClick(CameraRecordActivity.java:321)
                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4444)
                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18457)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5049)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my code when click:

```
 isShowMap = !isShowMap;
 FragmentTransaction ft = 
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 if (mapFragment.isAdded()) {
     ft.remove(mapFragment);
  }
 if (cameraPreviewFragment.isAdded()) {
   ft.remove(cameraPreviewFragment);
 }
 ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();

 getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
 ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 if (isShowMap) {
     mapFragment.showLogo();
     ft.add(R.id.big_fragment, mapFragment, MapFragment.TAG);
     ft.add(R.id.content_frame_small, cameraPreviewFragment, 
     CameraPreviewFragment.TAG);
  } else {
      mapFragment.disapperLogo();
      ft.add(R.id.big_fragment, cameraPreviewFragment, CameraPreviewFragment.TAG);
      ft.add(R.id.content_frame_small, mapFragment, MapFragment.TAG);
      cameraPreviewFragment.loadView(cameraManager)
  }
  ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

It seems

Comment: Include manager.executePendingTransactions() before adding the fragment for the second time.

Comment: It does not work for me When add MapFragment or CameraPreviewFragment to the big_fragment all of them show , But when add in content_frame_small all of them did not appear

Answer (score 0):

@Sarah Huang

> Here in your code you not commit transaction thats why your small
>   fragment is not shown.

```
ft.addToBackStack(MapFragment.TAG);
ft.add(R.id.content_frame_small, mapFragment, MapFragment.TAG);
```

You try to do this

```
  ft.addToBackStack(MapFragment.TAG);
  ft.add(R.id.content_frame_small, mapFragment, MapFragment.TAG).commit();
```

Comment: I executed the commit code below the add code. ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();

Comment: i think for every fragment transaction you have to call commit()